# verifying a password encrypted with bcrypt in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I have a code that verifies a password to log in, but when it comes to comparing it with the wrong password even though it is right, could someone help me

```
 login(req, res) {
    const { email, pass } = req.body;

    if (!email || !pass) {
        return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
    }
    console.log("email retrieved from req: ", email);
    console.log("length of email retrieved from req: ", email.length);

    database.select('*').table('login')
        .where({ email: email }).then(data => {
            const isValid = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, saltRounds);
            console.log("oiii") // Console.log esta entrando no IF que não vai
            if (data.senha === isValid) {
                return database.select('*').from('login')
                    .where({ email: email })
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json(user)
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get user'))
            } else {
                res.status(400).json('Senha Errada2')
            }
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Senha Errada1'))
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is English only. You may have better luck on [pt.so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use bcrypt.compare to compare the encrypted password from the database.

```
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
bcrypt.compare(someOtherPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
// result == false
});
```